# Convert a 4x4 RH Transformation Matrix to a LH (Unity) Transformation Matrix

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

I have a PLMXML document (Siemens NX/JT2Go) which contains various 4x4 transformation matrices for various models, the coordinate system of which is:

```
Right Handed
negative X forward
positive Z up
positive y right
```

I want to import the models into Unity by converting their respective transformation matrices.

I have read in numerous places that the axis can be swapped and that should be work. My matrices knowledge is rusty to say the least but know that the following matrix should give me the basis change I need:

```
| 0 1 0 0 |
| 0 0 1 0 | = rhsToLhs
|-1 0 0 0 |
| 0 0 0 1 |
```

With the following multiplication:

```
unityTransform = rhsToLhs * PLMTransform * rhsToLhs;
```

but this doesn't work.

My question is, what are the steps that I should be taking to perform this correctly?

I don't know the order in which the rotation matrix for the PLMXML is put together, so I don't think I can just extract it from the transformation matrix and manipulate it with the 3x3 version of the above matrix.

As I say, I'm pretty rusty with matrices and if anyone can push me in the right direction I'd be very appreciative.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I had a similar problem and i can not give you a proper solution but what i did was find two points that are transformed in my system (not Unity) then created cubes at the same location and find the convertion by trying all possibilities. You can take a look at this as [well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53452698/9242491) which can give you some idea.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I managed to get it working with one cube but then failed to recreate using a further examples with different transforms. It seems that the PLMXML coordinate rotation order is Rz * Rx * Ry but I'm not sure and I'm a bit stuck. A colleague is back from holiday next week and he's pretty good on this sort of thing. If he saves the day I'll post a solution on here.

Comment: Hello! There's something strange going on which and I can't seem to get a sensible output. However, I can say for certain that to get the rotations from RHS to LHS, you only need to extract the Quaternion and negate the i, j, and k parts. Then we have the rotation represented the opposite system.